# Populate dropdown based on checkbox

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that contains a checkbox and a dropdown list. I use PHP to populate the dropdown list from two MySQL tables. Which table I use depends on whether the checkbox was checked or not. But, as you can see from my code sample, I can only populate that dropdown list after I submit the form. I want to be able to keep clicking on the checkbox and keep re-populating the dropdown list without having to submit the form. I am still new to this, so, please, give me as simple a solution as possible.

PS. I have a small bug in the code that doesn't keep the checkbox checked/unchecked after I submit the form. Working on fixing it.

Thank you

---

```
<?php
$Prc_Earn = 'Prc';
if (isset($_POST['submitBtn']))
  {
    if (isset($_POST['chkbox']))
      {
        $sql = 'select distinct Symbol from price_history.quarterly_earnings_history';
        $Prc_Earn = 'Earn';
      }
    else
      {
        $sql = 'select distinct Symbol from price_history.stock_symbol_list';
        $Prc_Earn = 'Prc';
      }
    }
// Connect to the database
include ('../Connections/mysql_connect.php');
if ($dbcon)
  {
?>
    <form method='post'>
        <label for=''>Earnings / Prices</label>
        <input type='checkbox' name='chkbox' id='chkbox' <?php if ($Prc_Earn == 'Prc') { echo "checked"; };?>><br><br>

        <label for='symbol'>Stock Symbol:</label>
        <select name = 'symbol' id='symbol'>
<?php
        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
          {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              { echo '<option value="' . $row['Symbol'] . '">' . $row['Symbol'] . '</option>'; }
          }
?>
        </select><br><br>
        <button class='button' type='submit' name='submitBtn' id='submitBtn'>View Data</button><br><br>
    </form>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: You need to use Javascript with AJAX calls to achieve this. There should be plenty of tutorials on such things out there, but you might want to start with the [guide to AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I will need to learn how to do this with ajax. Thank you.